# Software for windows that allows the design of an electronic circuit with a simulator style interface and converts to latex

Tags: diagrams, software

I was looking to see if anyone knows of a program with a relatively simple interface that allows you to create a certain electronic circuit, like the one shown in the figure, and then convert it to latex language.

[image]

If possible I'm looking for one that is compatible with Windows 10. Thank you so much for all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why not use a dedicated package, such as `circuitikz` or `pst-circ`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bernard, yes, but I was looking for a software in wich I can draw the circuit, then press a button and generate the latex code

Comment: In this case, why not use a simple `\includegraphics`?

Comment: And could you tell me of a program that allows such graphics to be made in high quality? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only  a mathematician…

Comment: No problem! Thank you very much for everything.

Comment: As long as a circuit simulator could export to or print the image as pdf, say circ.pdf, you can include it: `\includegraphics{circ} ` ... // See package graphicx for details.